# Character segmentation of captcha image

Tags: image-processing, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, captcha, image-segmentation

I'm trying to crack a CAPTCHA image but I can't find a way to segment the characters.

I have this image:
[image]

I applied some filters and thresholding which resulted in this image:[image]

Now I need to segment the image to be used in a classifier such as SVM or ANN.

The problem is that some characters are connected, and I couldn't find a way to separate them.

More image examples:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Do anyone have an approach to segment the image and get the characters?

Comment: The CAPTCHA is purposely built in a way that makes your endeavor difficult.

Comment: I'm actually quite interested in how you remove the curvy lines in your examples. Did you use something similar to erosions?

Comment: @Kent Yes, I've used a combination of erosion and dilation to accomplish that.

Answer (score 5):

It seems to me that your characters have a maximum stroke width. Whenever you find a horizontal row of black pixels that is wider than this width, that indicates that two characters are joined here.

So

- for each connected blob that is wider than a single character

  - for each row of that blob

    - find all uninterrupted horizontal lines of black pixels in this row that are longer than MAX_STROKE_WIDTH
    - note the X-coordinate of the center of these lines
  - cluster the found X-coordinates
  - split the block at the center of each cluster with more than N coordinates.
  - (you can either simply split vertically, or try to fit a line through the points in the cluster)

Comment: Very good idea, I'll test it you and let you know how that behaves. Thank you.

Comment: Although this would break with characters such as the 'L' above that have a long horizontal component.

Answer (score 2):

This is a minimization problem.  The tricky part is picking the right metric, and making it fast.

1. Collect (manually) examples of every character (letter or number): at least several examples of each, cleaned up by hand
2. Solve the captcha (manually) for a suitably large number of examples (a few hundred).  This gives you a test data set.
3. Given an image, try to match it with slightly distorted versions of the example characters.  The best match can be considered as the one which has the least sum of K1 * white area in the image which is black in the match + K2 * black area in the image which is white in the match + K3 * distance between expected average position and orientation of characters and the position and orientation of characters in the match + K4 * the geometric distortion of characters.  This is the metric to minimize.  The values K1..K4 are suitable weights which you can find by optimizing the accuracy over your test data set.
4. This is a fairly large search space: however, since the spacing of characters is relatively regular, you can fit one character at a time, so a simple gradient descent over the position/distortion of a character (for every possible character) starting from the expected average position will find a good match, and you can pick the best match as the character that you think is there, then move on to the next one.  Total: 6 x (26 letters + 10 numbers) gradient descents over (roughly) 2 position + 1 tilt + 1 scale + 1 stretch dimensions.  Essentially, this breaks down the minimization problem described above into a problem of matching one character at a time, independently but sequentially.  Then mask out the found match and repeat for the next (adjacent) expected location until you have matches for all 6.  Based on the examples you provide, this will have very high confidence, ie the scores of the correct answers would be much better than any other answer (for each character individually).

P.S. This may be interesting: https://code.google.com/p/captchacker/

Comment: I didn't understand well your approach, in the item 3 you describe one way of matching the test characters given an image, in this algorithm do I need to slide each of the test characters horizontally in the image to find the best matches?

Answer (score 1):

Your approach seems to be too bottom-up to me.
The number of characters is constant and they seem to be mono-spaced
So just split the image by the width and make sure the features that you retrieve are rotational/scale invariant.
This can then be fed into an ANN. I don't see why you have to segment the characters.